# Passing custom Node parameters to Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

When running Cypress via its standard CLI (e.g. `cypress run`), I want it to pass the standard node parameter `--dns-result-order=ipv4first` to all instances of Node it creates. I cannot find any standard way of doing so in the documentation, is there any way to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

The Cypress runner only starts one Node instance, and during startup it invokes the config file `cypress.config.js`.

Here you could set the dns via API, ref [dns.setDefaultResultOrder(order)](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dnssetdefaultresultorderorder)

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

const dns = require('node:dns')
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead add a `script` to your `package.json` that sets the desired flag via the [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions) env var like:

```
"scripts": {
     "cypress:run": "NODE_OPTIONS='--dns-result-order=ipv4first' cypress run"
}
```

Then do `npm run cypress:run`.